# Code signing for ad hoc testing

Tags: ios, parse-platform, code-signing, provisioning-profile

i'm using Parse.com as my back-end back up for my data. Now i'm testing push notification on my device. i read their quick and long push tutorial, added the certificates and everything is fine. The only thing that confuses me is code signing. i created an ad hoc push distribution profile in order to test push on my device (i heard it's the closest thing to the app store profile). in the tutorial [Parse Push Notification Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) it's written is that i should change the target and the project code signing to "iOS Developer". Since i will be testing using the Ad Hoc Distribution Profile i guess i should place the iOS Distribution instead; and i places all the fields with iOS distribution (Debug/release). I ran the app, it runs fine until i interact with it it crashes with the following error:

> error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/0238BFCF-0A1F-47E5-AE74-3C6020F101B3/Demo.app' -- failed to get the task for process 182

Now i tried again while placing the "iOS Developer" instead, it also crashes with the following:

> error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/0238BFCF-0A1F-47E5-AE74-3C6020F101B3/Demo.app' -- failed to get the task for process 192

i then figured out there is a provisioning profile drop down menu. it was "None" on default, so i selected the ad hoc profile instead and tried again. and i also got this error:

> error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/0238BFCF-0A1F-47E5-AE74-3C6020F101B3/Demo.app' -- failed to get the task for process 241

Note: all the errors are also accompanied with the app crashing.

how can i fix that?! i guess i have tried every possible way. Any help, hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad Hoc/Distribution builds do not allow connecting with the debugger, so you'll have to settle for watching its output in the console of the `Xcode Organiser`.

The `Code Signing Identity` should be `iOS Distribution` and the provisioning profile should be your ad hoc one. You *can* set this in your build settings, but the usual way is to `Archive` then `Distribute` as Ad Hoc and then install onto your device.

You can also temporarily mangle your build settings, run, ignore the error and launch manually on the device.

Comment: i am running it on a device! it crashes and it shows me the errors i mentioned.

Comment: yes from Xcode.if it doesn't work how can i do that? thanks for your replies btw